# How to JSON serialize hh:mm:ss in Python? How to query its type?

Tags: python, json, datetime, serialization, time

I need to serialize a python object into JSON and am having a hard time converting time-counters into JSON-play-nice form

Say I have something like this:

```
 01:20:24    # hh:mm:ss
```

which is a time counter I'm increasing, while my script is running.

When done, I need to convert to JSON.

I'm currently trying this:

```
dthandler = lambda obj: obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, time) else None
this_object["totaltime"] = json.dumps(this_object["totaltime"], default=dthandler)
```

but I get an error on `time` being not a valid `class, type, or tuple of classes and types`

**Question:**
How do I serialize this? And is there a list of possible 'default-types' to query against (Python newbie... sorely missing Javascript typeof)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a JSON problem; your `time` reference is not what you think it is.

Make sure you have a `datetime.time` object there, and not the `time` module, for example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> ref = datetime.time(10, 20)
>>> isinstance(ref, time)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
>>> isinstance(ref, datetime.time)
True
```

If you use the *correct* type to test against, things work fine:

```
>>> import json
>>> dthandler = lambda obj: obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, datetime.time) else None
>>> json.dumps(ref, default=dthandler)
'"10:20:00"'
```

Note that the documentation expects the handler to raise a `TypeError` instead of returning `None`; that way unserializable objects are at least treated as errors:

```
def dthandler(o):
    try:
        return o.isoformat()
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError
```

would be more Pythonic and correct.

Comment: just checked. I have a `datetime.timedelta(0, 5)`

Comment: ok. I think I'm on the right track. Let's see if I can get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: more info, so you get the nod. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `time` variable isn't what you think it is (maybe referring to the `time` module instead of the class?).

**However**, it would be better not to make the instance check at all, since it's rather unpythonic. "Better to ask forgiveness..."

```
def dthandler(obj):
    try:
        return obj.isoformat()
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

This avoids the ugly type checking altogether, since what you really want is "return the isoformat result if I can; otherwise return None".